# Can't see deployed web apps on Tomcat

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea

I'm going through the book "Professional Java for Web Applications" and am running through some examples. I created a simple web application and deployed it to Tomcat. When I go to the manager portal at localhost:8080/manager I can see my deployed web app. However when I go to the tomcat directory ~/tomcat/webapps I don't see it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please explain how did u deploy?

Answer (score 0):

hmm try (all in tomcat's folder)

\work\Catalina\localhost

\server\webapps

\conf\Catalina\localhost (find your app xml)

maybe you have two installations?

Comment: I tried all those, nothing. I too thought maybe I have two installations (or something like that). However if I change the manager portal login info in this directory, I'm able to see the effects when trying to log in to the portal. So I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: hmm check the config files, maybe they point outside. You mentioned deploying, did you use netbeans or similar?

Comment: I'm deploying through IntelliJ. Which config files should I check?

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't copy your project to webapps, and makes tomcat run with a custom catalina root folder (pointing to your project), you should probably just copy it manually, or create a batch file to copy it if you must have it at webapps.

so again, if you want to follow your book to the T, find the compiled project (ends with .war extension), and copy it to webapps. Right now it runs inside IntelliJ because IntelliJ does some magic you dont have to learn atm :P